# Printing Reports with Icons as Values

Tags: reporting

We have a report whose field values are icons. The files are stored within Salesforce. We would like to be able to print that out but when we go into Printable View we are presented with an Excel spreadsheet of empty files with red "x" in them due to the unaccessible file.

What can I do about this ? I understand the file is not on my computer and therefore not accessible to Excel. So is there any kind of solution ?

[image: Report with icons]

[image: Printable view without icons]

Comment: Can you post a picture of how original report is displaying and how printable view is displaying

Comment: @SantanuBoral - thank you for your response. I have added pics to my original post, but I don't think they're visible. Let me know if you cannot see them.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution to this. Essentially, it's possible if you use Documents (we were using Content) ; and you have to use the "Externally Available Image" checkbox.

Use the full URL of the image in your formula field.

Here is the link to the solution : 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hjvAAAQ